# Router-link inside data function Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm looking to acces to the **news** component from this file with **path** but it isn't working, I've used also **to={...}** but still don't work. Could anybody give a good link for any kind of documentation to fix it?

thanks

```
 data() {
        return {
            settings: [{
                    title: "Profile"
                }, {
                    title: "E-mail"
                }, {

                    title: "News", path: "./News",
                }, {

                    title: "Custom"

                }, {

                    title: "Edit"
                }


            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean you want to get the url path of a route? Or you need the actual file location within your application?

Answer (score 0):

router should be set up like this

```
export default new Router({
mode: 'hash',
routes: [{
        path: '/',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        component: Login
    }
]})
```

Comment: I've already implemented on my main.js file all the routes for the component, but I'm looking to link **News** component from this  file.

Comment: Data section is looks fine , detail down more to see how you are using it